# Revising function to split out image and year

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code which loops through the `imgs` array and allows the user to click the image to step through the array to change the image each time an image is clicked. It's working fine - but I am trying to revise it - see below.

**Current Working Example**

```js
var imgs = [ "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/1.0.0/assets/svg/1F386.svg"
     , "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/1.5.0/assets/svg/1F386.svg"
     , "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/2.0.0/assets/svg/1F386.svg"
     , "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/2.1.0/assets/svg/1f386.svg"
     , "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/assets/3.0/png/128/1f386.png" ];
     
var imgs_count = imgs.length;

function changeImage(dir) {

    var img = document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange");
    img.src = imgs[imgs.indexOf(img.src) + (dir || 1)] || imgs[dir ? imgs.length - 1 : 0];
 
    var x = imgs.indexOf(img.src) + 1; // index of current image plus one
    var z = x + "/" + imgs_count; // concatenate the strings
    var versionDiv = document.getElementById('versions');
    versionDiv.textContent = z; //replace the text in the versions div

    var imgver = document.getElementById("versions");
    imgver.src = imgs_count;

}
```

```html
<div id="slideshow" style="margin:20px 0px -2px 0px; border:1px solid #eee; border-radius:5px; padding:20px; width:235px;">
        <center>
   <img alt="slideshow" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/1.0.0/assets/svg/1F386.svg" id="imgClickAndChange" onclick="changeImage()" width="128" height="128" />
  </center>
    </div>
 <div id="versions">1/5</div>
```

I would like to also include the year the image was released in each array element, after the image name, separated by a pipe:

```
var imgs = [ "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/1.0.0/assets/svg/1F386.svg|2018"
           , "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/1.5.0/assets/svg/1F386.svg|2017"
           , "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/2.0.0/assets/svg/1F386.svg|2016"
           , "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/2.1.0/assets/svg/1f386.svg|2015"
           , "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/assets/3.0/png/128/1f386.png|2014" ];
```

And then I'd like to split out that year data and display it in brackets after the text which starts with 1/5 and changes each time the image is clicked.

I am sort of close, but not close enough to get it to work:

```js
var imgs = [ "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/1.0.0/assets/svg/1F386.svg|2018"
     , "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/1.5.0/assets/svg/1F386.svg|2017"
     , "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/2.0.0/assets/svg/1F386.svg|2016"
     , "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/2.1.0/assets/svg/1f386.svg|2015"
     , "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/assets/3.0/png/128/1f386.png|2014" ];

var imgs_count = imgs.length;

function changeImage(dir) {

    var img = document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange");
    var array_data = imgs[imgs.indexOf(img.src) + (dir || 1)] || imgs[dir ? imgs.length - 1 : 0];
 img.src = array_data;
 
 var this_len = array_data.length;
 var pipe_pos = array_data.indexOf("|");
 var var_image = array_data.substr(0, pipe_pos);
 var var_year = array_data.substr(pipe_pos+1, this_len);

 console.log("array_data: " + array_data);
 console.log("this_len: " + this_len);
 console.log("pipe_pos: " + pipe_pos);
 console.log("var_image: " + var_image);
 console.log("var_year: " + var_year);
 
    var x = imgs.indexOf(img.src) + 1; // index of current image plus one
    var z = x + " / " + imgs_count; // concatenate the strings
    var versionDiv = document.getElementById('versions');
    versionDiv.textContent = z + " (" + var_year + ")"; //replace the text in the versions div

    var imgver = document.getElementById("versions");
    imgver.src = imgs_count;

}
```

```html
    <div id="slideshow" style="margin:20px 0px -2px 0px; border:1px solid #eee; border-radius:5px; padding:20px; width:235px;">
        <center>
   <img alt="slideshow" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/1.0.0/assets/svg/1F386.svg" id="imgClickAndChange" onclick="changeImage()" width="128" height="128" />
  </center>
    </div>
 <div id="versions">1/5 (2018)</div>
```

Click the image, and obviously the image doesn't display because it has a pipe and a year at the end of the image URL.

But the year changes each time I click the image, so I am managing to split out the year from the end of the image URL.

I can see from the console.log that I can extract the image url as well, from before the pipe, but if I change the code, from:

```
img.src = array_data;
```

To:

```
img.src = var_image;
```

After the lines of code where var_image and var_year is set, it breaks completely and as soon as I click the image, the years don't change and I can't progress from there:

```js
var imgs = [ "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/1.0.0/assets/svg/1F386.svg|2018"
     , "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/1.5.0/assets/svg/1F386.svg|2017"
     , "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/2.0.0/assets/svg/1F386.svg|2016"
     , "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/2.1.0/assets/svg/1f386.svg|2015"
     , "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/assets/3.0/png/128/1f386.png|2014" ];

var imgs_count = imgs.length;

function changeImage(dir) {

    var img = document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange");
    var array_data = imgs[imgs.indexOf(img.src) + (dir || 1)] || imgs[dir ? imgs.length - 1 : 0];
 
 var this_len = array_data.length;
 var pipe_pos = array_data.indexOf("|");
 var var_image = array_data.substr(0, pipe_pos);
 var var_year = array_data.substr(pipe_pos+1, this_len);
 
 img.src = var_image;

 console.log("array_data: " + array_data);
 console.log("this_len: " + this_len);
 console.log("pipe_pos: " + pipe_pos);
 console.log("var_image: " + var_image);
 console.log("var_year: " + var_year);
 
    var x = imgs.indexOf(img.src) + 1; // index of current image plus one
    var z = x + " / " + imgs_count; // concatenate the strings
    var versionDiv = document.getElementById('versions');
    versionDiv.textContent = z + " (" + var_year + ")"; //replace the text in the versions div

    var imgver = document.getElementById("versions");
    imgver.src = imgs_count;

}
```

```html
    <div id="slideshow" style="margin:20px 0px -2px 0px; border:1px solid #eee; border-radius:5px; padding:20px; width:235px;">
        <center>
   <img alt="slideshow" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/1.0.0/assets/svg/1F386.svg" id="imgClickAndChange" onclick="changeImage()" width="128" height="128" />
  </center>
    </div>
 <div id="versions">1/5 (2018)</div>
```

I am probably doing something silly but I can't work out what.

---

Following on from the very helpful answer from irkeninvader, I wonder if I can change this code I had to step through the next / previous images using the comma and period keys on the keyboard:

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.keyCode == '188') {
        changeImage(-1) //left <- show Prev image
    } else if (e.keyCode == '190') {
        // right -> show next image
        changeImage()
    }
}
```

The code works, but now each key only goes forward through the images, wherease the old version using my ugly code, would step back through the images on pressing the comma, and forward using the period / full stop.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the `src` and `year` of your images in separate properties in order to avoid confusing string splitting logic.

I refactored your code a decent amount (hope you don't mind) just to show another way to approach this problem.

Keeping track of your image array and current index starts to get messy so I introduced an `ImageManager` to handle all the messy parts.

The ImageManager contains the Imgs array and has functions to grab the next image plus a few more to make updating the ui a little easier.

`ImageModel` is a simple function that returns an object with `ImageSource` and `Year` properties to avoid having to split information out of a single string.

---

Hopefully this makes sense, it's basically just a way to tidy up where your information is stored and use multiple small functions to make sure no one area of code feels messy of overwhelming.

This can be taken further, maybe `ImageManager` could store the currently selected `ImageModel` and return the whole versionDiv information string so the `changeImage` function doesn't have to add strings together.

Anywhere you feel is getting complicated just break it down into smaller functions with good names.  Have fun!

```js
var manager = new ImageManager();

document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.keyCode == '188') {
        changeImage('Previous'); //left <- show Prev image
    } else if (e.keyCode == '190') {        
        changeImage('Next'); // right -> show next image
    }
}

function changeImage(direction) {
    var img = document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange");
    var versionDiv = document.getElementById('versions');
    
    var model;
    if(direction === 'Next'){
      model = manager.NextImage();    
    }
    
    if(direction === 'Previous'){
      model = manager.PreviousImage();    
    }      
    
    img.src = model.ImageSrc;        
    versionDiv.textContent = manager.ImageProgressString() + ' [' + model.Year + ']';  //replace the text in the versions div
}

changeImage('Next');

function ImageManager() {
  var self = this;
  self.Imgs = []; 
  self.Index = -1;
  
  function Init(){
    self.Imgs.push(ImageModel('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/1.0.0/assets/svg/1F386.svg', '2018'));
    self.Imgs.push(ImageModel('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/1.5.0/assets/svg/1F386.svg', '2017'));
    self.Imgs.push(ImageModel('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/2.0.0/assets/svg/1F386.svg', '2016'));
    self.Imgs.push(ImageModel('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/2.1.0/assets/svg/1f386.svg', '2015'));
    self.Imgs.push(ImageModel('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/assets/3.0/png/128/1f386.png', '2014'));         
  }
  
  self.NextImage = function() {    
    self.AddToIndex(1);
    return self.Imgs[self.Index];            
  }
  
  self.PreviousImage = function() {    
    self.AddToIndex(-1);
    return self.Imgs[self.Index];            
  }  
  
  self.ImageProgressString = function() {
    return (self.Index + 1) + '/' + self.Imgs.length;
  }
  
  self.AddToIndex = function(change) {    
    var len = self.Imgs.length;
    self.Index = (self.Index + change + len) % len;
  }
  
  Init();   
}

function ImageModel(img, year) {
  return { ImageSrc: img, Year: year };
}
```

```html
<div id="slideshow" style="margin:20px 0px -2px 0px; border:1px solid #eee; border-radius:5px; padding:20px; width:235px;">
  <center>
    <img alt="slideshow" id="imgClickAndChange" onclick="changeImage('Next')" width="128" height="128" />
  </center>
</div>
<div id="versions"></div>
```

Comment: Wow @IrkenInvader - that is wonderful, thank you. Of course I don't mind that you rewrote my ugly code and made it a whole lot better, and fixed the issue. I really appreciate your help and guidance. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @IrkenInvader - I have updated the question to ask if a bit of code I was using can be revised to use the comma and period on the keyboard to step back / forward through the images. Sorry to ask - I wondered if I could ask for your help again please? Thanks

Comment: Glad you liked the answer!  Yeah adding a PreviousImage() to ImageManager would be a decent way to do it

Comment: @4532066 Updated the answer

Comment: you have gone above and beyond! Thank you once again, it amazes me how generous people are with their time and skills. I revised your code as well to add in a 3rd attribute (version) and it was so much simpler than the substring hacking method I tried before. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to add to it! I've been in similar spots lots of times and I know how frustrating it can be, paying forward all the help I got :)